# nestjs Commands not working without using npx?

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs, npx

I installed nestjs using npm but it is not working without using npx.
For Every nest command I have to write npx ahead
like

```
npx nest -v
```

otherwise it does'nt work.

also it shows error in @nestjs/core and other nestjs packages.

due to this I am not able to run projects.

OS : Windows

Comment: you need to install it globally for that to work without `npx`, i.e. `npm i -g @nestjs/cli` see https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview npx runs commands installed within your project, i.e. they are in package.json. You also need to run `npm install` in a freshly checked out project for npm to install all the dependencies, maybe that causes your other errors.

Comment: I don't recommend installing it globally. Use npx or yarn and you'll be safer. `npx @nestjs/cli` when running outside of any project

Comment: I have tried npm i -g @nestjs/cli still no good.

Comment: After installing it globally did you restart your shell? If your npm global install in your `PATH`?

Comment: I have restarted the cmd but it does not set path variables for it. I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed NPM without its global dependency binaries
on `PATH` environment variable. The path to NPM binaries looks like: `C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Roaming\npm`

- After setting up the `PATH`, if you opened the terminal via File Explorer, you've to restart the explorer and launch the terminal again. The same applies if you used a code editor app such as Visual Studio Code to launch the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
C:\Users\user\.npmrc
```

and there change there change the
changed the prefix value there from ~ to user\npm-global
it should look something like

```
prefix=C:\Users\{username}\npm-global
```

there should be no files between {username} and npm-global